# Как изменить содержимое ~/.local/ в unix?

Tags: linux, unix, файлы

Какие файловые менеджеры могут изменять содержимое данной папки?

Comment: уточните, что именно вас интересует: то, что написано в заголовке, или то, что написано в тексте вопроса?

Answer (score 5):

Папка `~/.local/` в linux отличается от большинства других папок в `~` единственным - ее название начинается с точки, что делает ее в некотором роде "скрытой". Эта скрытость заключается лишь в том, что команда `ls` без опций `-a`/`-A` ее не показывает, права на нее такие же, как и на сам `/home/username`, т.е. делать Вы с ней можете что захотите - хоть удаляйте.
Как написал Gennadiy Zolotarev, в консоли:

```
cd ~/.local
touch testfile
ls -A
rm testfile
```

midnight-commander (`mc`) по умолчанию показывает скрытые папки и файлы (включение/выключение этого режима меню `Options->Panel options` чекбокс `Show hidden files`). Чтобы заставить `nautilus` (Ubuntu) показывать скрытые файлы - нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> или в меню `edit->preferences` вкладка `views` галочка на чекбоксе `show hidden files` (У меня англ. версия Ubuntu).

Также, файлы (папки в линукс также являются файлами) имя которых начинается с точки не входят в "маску" `*`, т.е. например:

```
cd ~
mkdir test
cd test
touch x
touch .x
rm *
```

удалит файл `x`, но не удалит файл `.x`. (ВАЖНО: не рекомендую набирать в консоли команду `rm .*`)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, mc https://www.midnight-commander.org/. Но зачем файловый менеджер, если это прекрасно делается в шелле?

```
[user@host ~]$ cd ~/.local
[user@host .local]$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 gz gz 4096 Nov 14 20:29 share
[user@host .local]$
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).